# highcharts bubble chart legend with unique numbers

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Please have a look at [this bubble-chart picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tW4K3.jpg).

You see I have 3 series `bundle`, `system` and `product`.
Within these series a number makes them unique.
Each bubble has a "name" which is very long unfortunately.

Now I had the Idea, that I put that into the legend not into the bubble itself.

Is this possible?

Comment: Just curious, why did you choose X, Y, and C? It would be funny if it was because C sounds like "Zee", which is how some people pronounce Z

Comment: It's simply a funny coincidence. My german pronunciation für letter "Z" is "Zet" ;)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want a number in the legend instead of "bundle", "system" and "product"? What am I missing?

Comment: How about splitting then your series into separate ones, where each series is just one point. Then use [`labelFormatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.labelFormatter) to get desired output. But I'm pretty sure legend will hard to read..

Comment: @ Ondkloss: I changed the picture in the way I'd love to have this legend. @Pawel Fus: But I still want the color Icons in the legend to match with the bubbles in the chart -> if there are 3 red bubbles, legend should have 3 red bubble icons as well.

Comment: Colors will match, just try it. You can set color per series this way: `series: [{ color: 'rgba(0,10,10, 0.5)', data: [ ... ] }]`.